# dynamically change ticker interval

Tags: go, ticker

I would like to change my ticker interval dynamically.

I've written down an example to show you how I did. My use case is something else than an "accelerometer" but I hope that it gives you an idea.

http://play.golang.org/p/6ANFnoE6pA

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "log"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    interval := float64(1000)

    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Duration(interval) * time.Millisecond)
    go func(){
        counter := 1.0
        for range ticker.C {
            log.Println("ticker accelerating to " + fmt.Sprint(interval/counter) + " ms")
            ticker = time.NewTicker(time.Duration(interval/counter) * time.Millisecond)
            counter++
        }
        log.Println("stopped")
    }()
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    log.Println("stopping ticker")
    ticker.Stop()
}
```

What is wrong is that the ticker will always "tick" every seconds and it doesn't accelerate... Any idea?

Comment: The code has data race

Comment: Because the for loop is still using the channel from the old ticker object and not using the channels from the new ticker objects.

Comment: Thanks for your feedbacks. @BleedingFingers I see the data race (on the ticker var), but in this case shouldn't get a panic? Otherwise the pointer should be replaced with the new one. 

@ NipunTalukdar I have thought the same too, if this is right - then means that the ticker pointer is "cached" in the range-loop and overriding is not possible. I will try this with another example.

Comment: Yep, @NipunTalukdar, I guess that the ```range``` method caches the variable to be looped, then I think that overidding of the ticker like I suggested (using ```range```) is not possible - http://play.golang.org/p/yZvrgURz4o

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Following the answer to @fzerorubigd but a little more complete.

As said before, we can't use the `range` for this case, because the `range` loop caches the variable to be lopped and then it can't be overwritten (example here: http://play.golang.org/p/yZvrgURz4o )

Then, we should use a `for`-`select` combination loop. Hereafter the working solution:

http://play.golang.org/p/3uJrAIhnTQ

```
package main

import (
    "time"
    "log"
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    start_interval := float64(1000)
    quit := make(chan bool)

    go func(){
        ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Duration(start_interval) * time.Millisecond)
        counter := 1.0

        for {
            select {
            case <-ticker.C:
                log.Println("ticker accelerating to " + fmt.Sprint(start_interval/counter) + " ms")
                ticker.Stop()
                ticker = time.NewTicker(time.Duration(start_interval/counter) * time.Millisecond)
                counter++
            case <-quit:
                ticker.Stop()
                log.Println("..ticker stopped!")
                return
            }
        }
    }()

    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)

    log.Println("stopping ticker...")
    quit<-true

    time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond) // just to see quit messages
}
```

Comment: Will creating new `time.NewTicker` increase overhead of the garbage collection?

Comment: good question @chinuy - I would say that GC is needed there even if I am doing a replacement of the var ```ticker```. If you look at the code of ```time.NewTicker``` [HERE](https://golang.org/src/time/tick.go?s=706:740#L11) you can see that it creates some local structs that need to be collected at some point by the garbage collector. In conclusion: yes, it increase the overhead of GC

Answer (score 5):

that why in go1.15 `ticker.Reset` is Introduced, you don't need to create a new ticker update the existing ticker's duration with `ticker.Reset("new duration")`, and now you will not have any cache issues

[Go playground](https://play.golang.org/p/elV-eafPRzV)

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    interval := float64(1000)

    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Duration(interval) * time.Millisecond)
    go func(){
        counter := 1.0
        for range ticker.C {
            log.Println("ticker accelerating to " + fmt.Sprint(interval/counter) + " ms")
            ticker.Reset(time.Duration(interval/counter) * time.Millisecond)
            counter++
        }
        log.Println("stopped")
    }()
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    log.Println("stopping ticker")
    ticker.Stop()
}
```

The reason your example have a cache issue is that when you reassign the `ticker` variable with a `*time.ticker` struct you just unlink the original `*time.ticker` struct from the `ticker` variable but the loop is still tide to the original ticker channel you need to reassin a new loop to the new `time.ticker.c`

Comment: Although reset does work, the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Timer.Reset) states `Reset should be invoked only on stopped or expired timers with drained channels.` So I wouldn't suggest resetting an active ticker.

Comment: you confusing it with `time.timer{}.Reset()` on `time.tiker{}.Reset()` dosn't have this worning, here is the [documentation](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Ticker.Reset) for it

Comment: It's worth noting `ticker.Reset` method is available from go1.15.

Comment: Please explain what’s your problem with go1.15? The compiler will work with older code

Comment: @Issac it's not a problem, but worth noting. I used earlier version (1.14) and it didn' work.

Answer (score 1):

As Nipun Talukdar mentioned, the "for" capture the channel and use the same reference for iterate. it fixed if you use it like this :

[playground](http://play.golang.org/p/AEygFsb-7W)

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    interval := float64(1000)

    ticker := time.NewTicker(time.Duration(interval) * time.Millisecond)
    go func() {
        counter := 1.0
        for {
            select {
            case <-ticker.C:
                log.Println("ticker accelerating to " + fmt.Sprint(interval/counter) + " ms")
                ticker = time.NewTicker(time.Duration(interval/counter) * time.Millisecond)
                counter++
            }
        }
        log.Println("stopped")
    }()
    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    log.Println("stopping ticker")
    ticker.Stop()
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yep, I thought too that using ```for```-loop instead ```range```-loop can solve the issue. Just pay attention that when using ```for```-loop you should manage the incoming channel with a ```select```-catcher. To avoid confusing other developers - I will accept your answer if you edit the ```for```-code using the correctly ```select```-cases.

Comment: The select is not doing anything special when the case is single. but I get the idea and the code is updated.

Comment: my feedback was related to the "exit" function - to release all the variables used in the goroutines the ```for```-loop should return. This happens even in single-case.  Btw it was not asked, want just to be more precise ;-)

Comment: It is worth noticing that when you call ticker.Stop() you don't actually close its channel, so the `log.Println("stopped")` line will never be reached. You should keep a secondary channel to signal when you're done and then `select` between the ticker and the secondary channel. You should also be stopping every old ticker before creating a new one.

Comment: @hbejgel the ticker.C is a receive-only channel. you can not close a receive-only channel. the owner of channel who has the whole ref to it can close it. see https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Ticker

Comment: I am aware of this, and because of that you will never escape the `for` loop inside the goroutine. Therefore the goroutine will never print the expected line `stopped`

Answer (score 0):

What about this code:

https://play.golang.org/p/wyOTVxUW5Xj

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "log"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    startInterval := float64(1000)
    quit := make(chan bool)

    go func() {
        counter := 1.0
        for {
            select {
            case <-time.After(time.Duration(startInterval/counter) * time.Millisecond):
                log.Println("ticker accelerating to " + fmt.Sprint(startInterval/counter) + " ms")
                counter++
            case <-quit:
                log.Println("..ticker stopped!")
                return
            }
        }
    }()

    time.Sleep(5 * time.Second)
    log.Println("stopping ticker...")
    quit <- true
    time.Sleep(500 * time.Millisecond) // just to see quit messages
}
```